# Windows Authentication Complex AD Group Names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-roles

I'm using Windows Authentication and AD groups as roles. I got the following to work:

```
@User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\ADGroupName")
```

After some testing, it seems this only works with the Display Name, not the Alias of the AD group. Most groups in our domain have complex naming like:

```
@User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\*DEPT/TEAM/A&BC Developers")
```

This returns false, even if you are in a group with the same name. How can I get `@User.IsInRole("")` to recognize such complex group names?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `@` as a prefix to your string:

```
@User.IsInRole(@"DOMAIN\*DEPT/TEAM/A&BC Developers")
```

Or if you assign the string to a variable ahead of time:

```
@{
    string group = @"DOMAIN\*DEPT/TEAM/A&BC Developers";
}

@User.IsInRole(group)
```